# Mysql compare two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in the same database with matching id's.

The first table is `accounts`

```
id - account_access - name - email - city - state - etc...  
1 - 1 - Mark - mark@mark.com - Seattle - WA - blah,blah,blah  
2 - 1 - Dave - dave@dave.com - Portland - OR - blah,blah,blah  
3 - 0 - Jake - jake@jake.com - San Francisco - CA - blah,blah,blah  
4 - 1 - Julie - julie@julie.com - Los Andeles - CA - blah,blah,blah
```

The second table is `members`

```
 id - status - score - IQ  
 1 - 4 - 9000 - 108  
 2 - 5 - 8000 - 90  
 3 - 5 - 1000 - 25 (Disclaimer: Any relation to real people is purely coincidental)  
 4 - 5 - 5000 - 60
```

Since Jake wasn't very bright, he has zero access to the account.

What I want to know is how many people with account_access (1) have status (5), or how many people with status (5) have access.
I'm not familiar with how to word the SELECT statement comparing two tables, i would     like to know number of rows and then to also retrieve the data to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is a left join.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Accounts
LEFT JOIN members
ON Accounts.id = members.id
WHERE status = 5
AND account_access = 1
```

Additional info on Left Joins: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: If you want to retrieve the data to display select the separate elements SELECT blah, blah2, count(*) as COUNT.

Comment: A left join...I'm going to look that up. And count(*) counts? I was thinking mysql_num_rows.

Comment: Yep, count will return the number of results:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: I didn't expect to learn that, thanks. What is that part called "accounts.id" that's a table and column, surprised I have not caught on to that yet, is that standard or only in this instance.

Comment: That determines which column to join the two tables on. It's fairly standard for joins, but you can also use the "using" keyword.

Here's MySQL's official page on joins, its a pain to read through but very worth it in the end.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: So I'm joining the two tables on (or using) the id column then mysql does it's thing in the WHERE clause. Then accounts.id=members.id must match the FROM and LEFT JOIN? As in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Select count(*) from accounts left join members using (id) where account access = 1 and status = 5;

I don't have the underscore in my bb, so you may have to substitute the space between account and access with an underscore before running the query.

Comment: I like how you used "using (id)" didn't notice that right away, I'm gonna try that in my testing of the code. Thanks Chin!